# Recursively download maven artifacts of particular groupid and version

Tags: maven, wget

For the purpose of checking software licenses, I need to download all artifacts (source jars) of a particular group id and a particular version from the maven repo. There are many artifacts under this group id and many version too. So need to recursively find all artifacts under the groupid.

I tried this wget command but it doesn't seem to recurse into the directories below.

```
wget \
--accept-regex '.*-1.1.1-sources.jar$' \
--execute robots=off \
--recursive \
--no-parent \
--level=0 \
-U "Any User Agent" \
--reject '*.html*' \
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/theGroupId/
```

Is it possible to do this with wget or any other tool?

(The artifacts are from third party software that runs as a standalone process. My code doesn't have direct maven dependencies with it.)

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a look here: https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/

Comment: Why not just look at the licenses of the artifacts that you actually use as dependencies? (see comment from khmarbaise)

Comment: @JFabianMeier It's a third party software that runs as a standalone process. My code only communicates with it via REST api. There are no direct maven dependencies.

Comment: Still, I don't understand your requirements. Why are you interested in all artifacts of a given groupId? If you are not using the JARs, why do you need the license?

Comment: this software is packaged within our product and after installation it is run as standalone process.  For example, tomcat.